# Does travel insurance cover a leg for an unrelated airline?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, insurance

I will fly THY from ORD to IST.  I have to take another flight, with United, to get to ORD.  I am buying the tickets separately because that will save me a lot of money.

I am worried about the weather, since I'll be flying in winter.  I think it will be a good idea to buy travel insurance.  Do travel insurances generally cover all legs, if one leg is canceled (or a leg is missed because another was delayed)?  What is a good way to minimize the risk here?

Comment: This depends entirely on the travel insurance policy you purchase.

Comment: Michael's not just making a point for the sake of being pernickety.  If you buy the carrier's travel insurance, that generally only covers the carrier's journey; how you get to their start point, or what you do after their end point, is not their problem.  If you buy a single-trip policy from a third-party, it will cover whatever you declare as the journey.  If you buy an annual policy from a third-party, it will cover all journeys you take (within the rules) during that year.  Assuming you're thinking single-trip cover, it may matter very much *who* you get it from.

Comment: @MadHatter information like that is why I used the term 'generally', and exactly why Michael Hampton's comment is not helpful.  Thank you for providing more information to a novice like myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally yes, travel insurance includes coverage for canceled flights, and the associated costs including run-on flights on the itinerary, and typically coverage is structured to that it is applied over set time period (rather than eg only covering you on a per-flight basis).

So in general, for the vast majority of travel insurance products out there, they cover flight cancellation in this way. So yes you probably would be covered. However it is essential that you read your policy wording when contracting any such insurance, to make sure that this is the case.